# Пошаговое создание Label's в окне LabelFrame, нажимая на кнопку

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Есть кнопка:

```
but1 = Button(icon, text="Show the solution...", font="Arial 14", command=show)
but1.grid(column=1, row=3)
```

И есть обработчик события при нажатии на нее:

```
def show():
            lf = LabelFrame(icon, text="Solution", font='Arial 12')
            lf.grid(column=0, row=5, columnspan=4)
            Label(lf, text='1) A - B = {f1}\n'
                           '2) B & A = {f2}\n'
                           '3) (A - B) | (B & A) = {f3}\n'
                           '4) ( (A - B) | (B & A) ) \ (C | B)  = {rez}\n'
                           'Result: {rez}'
              .format(f1=log_oper.difference(self.A, self.B), f2=self.B & self.A, f3=(log_oper.difference(self.A, self.B))|(self.B&self.A), rez=initeq.initial_eq(self.A,self.B,self.C),font='Arial 14', justify=LEFT)).grid(column=0, row=5, sticky=W, columnspan=4)
```

Тоесть в окне `LabelFrame` создается `Label` с текстом:

```
'1) A - B = {f1}\n'
'2) B & A = {f2}\n'
'3) (A - B) | (B & A) = {f3}\n'
'4) ( (A - B) | (B & A) ) \ (C | B)  = {rez}\n'
'Result: {rez}'
```

И здесь вопрос:
Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку выводилось пошагово по одному пункту с того текста?
Это может быть или автоматически , или 5 раз нажать на кнопку.

Comment: Что такое `log_oper`? Почему не просто `self.A - self.B` вместо `log_oper.difference()`?

Comment: @insolor это не сильно имеет значения

Comment: Обычно это имеет значение. Зачем делать сложно, если можно сделать просто?

Comment: Вы правы, но это не решает мою проблему

Comment: Ответ vadim vaduha решает вашу проблему, нужно просто добавить format.

Comment: @insolor никак не получается его добавить(

Comment: См. мой комментарий под ответом (это один из вариантов). Вместо трех точек естественно параметры нужно подставить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import tkinter
import random


class Main(tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        lf = tkinter.LabelFrame(text="Solution")
        lf.grid()
        self.label_1 = tkinter.Label(lf, text='')

        self.label_2 = tkinter.Label(lf, text='')

        self.label_3 = tkinter.Label(lf, text='')

        self.label_4 = tkinter.Label(lf, text='')

        self.label_5 = tkinter.Label(lf, text='')

        self.button = tkinter.Button(self, text='Нажать', command=self.check).grid()
        self.button_remove = tkinter.Button(self, text='удалить', command=self.remove).grid()
        self.number_random()

    def check(self):
        if self.label_1["text"] == "":
            self.label_1["text"] = "1) %d - %d = %d" % (self.A, self.B, self.A - self.B)
            self.label_1.grid()
        elif self.label_2["text"] == "":
            self.label_2["text"] = "2) %d & %d = %d" % (self.B, self.A, self.B & self.A)
            self.label_2.grid()
        elif self.label_3["text"] == "":
            self.label_3["text"] = "3) (%d - %d) | (%d & %d) = %d" % (self.A, self.B, self.B, self.A,
                                                                      (self.A - self.B) | (self.B & self.A))
            self.label_3.grid()
        elif self.label_4["text"] == "":
            self.label_4["text"] = "4) ((%d - %d) | (%d & %d) ) \ (%d | %d)  = %d" % \
                                   (self.A, self.B, self.B, self.A, self.C, self.B,
                                    ((self.A - self.B) | (self.B & self.A))/(self.C | self.B))
            self.label_4.grid()
        elif self.label_5["text"] == "":
            self.label_5["text"] = "Result: %s" % str(((self.A - self.B) | (self.B & self.A))/(self.C | self.B))
            self.label_5.grid()
            self.after_cancel()
        self.after(1000, self.check)

    def remove(self):
        if self.label_1["text"] != "":
            self.label_1.grid_remove()
            self.label_1["text"] = ""
        elif self.label_2["text"] != "":
            self.label_2.grid_remove()
            self.label_2["text"] = ""
        elif self.label_3["text"] != "":
            self.label_3.grid_remove()
            self.label_3["text"] = ""
        elif self.label_4["text"] != "":
            self.label_4.grid_remove()
            self.label_4["text"] = ""
        elif self.label_5["text"] != "":
            self.label_5.grid_remove()
            self.label_5["text"] = ""
            self.number_random()
            self.after_cancel()
        self.after(1000, self.remove)

    def number_random(self):
        self.A = random.randrange(0, 1000)
        self.B = random.randrange(0, 1000)
        self.C = random.randrange(0, 1000)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main = Main()
    main.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import tkinter

Text = '''
    1) A - B = {f1} 
    2) B & A = {f2} 
    3) (A - B) | (B & A) = {f3} 
    4) ( (A - B) | (B & A) ) \ (C | B)  = {rez} 
    Result: {rez}'''

def show(iter_text, parent):
    '''Пошаговое создание Label's в окне LabelFrame, нажимая на кнопку'''
    text = next(iter_text, '')
    if text:
        tkinter.Label(parent, text=text).pack()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    # выводилось пошагово по одному пункту
    i_text = iter(filter(bool, map(str.strip, Text.split('\n'))))

    but1 = tkinter.Button(text="Show the solution...", command=lambda: show(i_text, parent=lf))
    lf = tkinter.LabelFrame(text="Solution")

    but1.pack()
    lf.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Ответ рабочий, нужно только добавить format, чтобы выводились значения, как-то так: `i_text = iter(filter(bool, map(str.strip, Text.format(...).split('\n'))`

Comment: поскольку у меня множества (`set()`) , поэтому не подходит `split` для них